# How do you query a parquet file using parquet-mr?

Tags: java, parquet, parquet-mr

I have a parquet file stored in AWS S3 that I want to query. I want to retrieve a certain row of data given that it equals a value. Almost like I would in SQL:

`SELECT * FROM file.parquet WHERE id = '1234';`

I am using `parquet-mr` to load it in to memory directly from S3 and read it and have it set up with a `AvroParquetReader` to read the rows.

I've copied every row into a Map for easy querying for now, however is there a better way to do this? The documentation for `parquet-mr` is not great, and most tutorials use deprecated methods.

Here is some example code of what i've got:

```
final ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = AvroParquetReader
                .<GenericRecord>builder(internalPath)
                .withConf(parquetConfiguration).build();
```

You can use `reader.read()` to get the next row in the file (which is what i've used to put it in to a `HashMap`, but I can't find any methods in `parquet-mr` that allow you to query a file without loading the entire file in to memory.

Comment: AWS Athena offers exactly this feature: being able to run SQL-like queries on top of parquet files stored in S3. https://aws.amazon.com/athena/
Or you could use Presto directly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_(SQL_query_engine)

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called predicate pushdown. You can read about it and find examples [here](https://ndolgov.blogspot.com/2016/11/parquet-file-filtering-with-predicate.html).